# Articles when describing video games

Tags: nouns, articles

Let's imagine that you are browsing a list of games and stumble across a game called Wheelie 6. You've never heard of it before and have never played the previous five games.

> Wheelie is back... in the past! Help him travel through (a|the) fantasy land and rescue (a|the) princess from (an|the) evil car wizard.

1. What articles do you expect to see in the sentence above considering that Wheelie has never been to fantasy lands before, has never rescued any princess, and has never encountered evil wizards?
2. Can "a" and "the" be interchangeable in this case?

For me, as a non-native speaker, "a" fits better since the land/princess/wizard was a new piece of information for me at the time when I first read the description, and the context is way too thin to "define" all of them with "the".

For some reason, though, the original description (I found it on Google Play) has "the" in front of all of the aforementioned nouns. It bugs me. Please, help me understand.

Comment: Yes; here, 'the' is licensed by 'the one defined by the game just mentioned (even though unfamiliar to the newbie)'. It also sounds more inclusive-enticing, less distanced, more decisive/polished and less schoolboyish even, than 'a'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your elaborate answer, Edwin. I'd like to ask one follow-up question in that regard. If the sentence was composed in a more "introductory" way, would it be appropriate to use "a" instead? Say, "Wheelie 6 is a point-and-click adventure game. Find yourself stranded on **a** fantasy land taken over by **an** evil wizard, travel through it to defeat him, and meet **a** beautiful princess along the way." Do the bold "**a**"s sound natural in this case?

Comment: The 'a's are what should be used in this case and sound fine; 'the' would be the wrong choice.